# Undeclared identifier: VRF_V2_Wrapper.calculateRequestPrice()

Tags: blockchain, chainlink, chainlink-keepers

I have been trying to use VRF tool, where VRFV2WrapperConsumerBase.sol has been changed to VRF_V2_Wrapper. Now, I am facing this issue after I made above changes:
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4coz.png)

I tried to update as per the new version, but I have no idea what to use in this, and as such I am facing error.

Comment: You have a Solidity syntax error based on the error message in the terminal. Can you please edit the question and paste the smart contract source code? I don't see the error part in the image, so can't tell how to fix it atm. Thanks in advance